# SWIFT error creating SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I'm new on SWIFT programming, and as usual i have a problem, maybe it's nothing, but I'll be glad if u can help me understanding where I wrong.
Sorry for the italian variables name, but this leaned to be a try so I prefer to do in italian....

```
import UIKit

class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var listaSpesa = [Alimento]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()   //SearchBar

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //inizializzazione di una lista con l'aggiunta di elementi alla lista
    self.listaSpesa = [
        Alimento(categoria: ["Dolci"], nome: "cioccolato"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Dolci"], nome: "barrette energetiche"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Dolci", "Altro"], nome: "caramelle"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Carne","Dolci"], nome: "cotolette"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Carne"], nome: "polpette"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Altro"], nome: "dentifricio"),
        Alimento(categoria: ["Altro"], nome: "carta alluminio")
    ]

    //aggiorna la tabella ricaricando le funzioni
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    //Aggiungo la SearchBar
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        // creo un oggetto di tipo UISearchController
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        // il searchResultsUpdater, ovvero colui che gestirà gli eventi di ricerca, sarà la ListaTableViewController (o self)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // rimuove la tableView di sottofondo in modo da poter successivamente visualizzare gli elementi cercati
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        // impongo alla searchBar, contenuta all'interno del controller, di adattarsi alle dimensioni dell'applicazioni
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        // atacco alla parte superiore della TableView la searchBar (la visualizzo)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        // restituisco il controller creato
        return controller
    })()
}
}
```

this is the part where i have problems, please, help me, everywhere i went says the same things that i've done...
This is the string where I have the error

```
controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

And this is the error:

```
(Cannot assign a value of type 'ListaTableViewController' to a value of type 'UISearchResultUpdating?')
```

P.S.
sorry for my english ^^'

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchResultUpdating` is a protocol. You need to tell the compiler that you intend to implement that, by putting it in the line where you declare your class,

```
class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultUpdating
```

You will get another error if you don't actually implement the required methods in that protocol.

Comment: based on my code, how could I resolve the second error (that I have when I'm gonna update my class declaration)?
sorry, but as I sayid I'm just learning it...

Comment: @Narak, You should look at the documentation for `UISearchResultUpdating`, and implement the one method it contains.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring UISearchResultUpdating as mentioned:

```
class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultUpdating
```

The error exists as long as one does not implement the required function.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
```

It´s simply a confusing error message ;-)
"ListaTableViewController does not confirm to protocol UISearchResultUpdating" would be more helpful.